# Use `winget upgrade PACKAGE_NAME` within NodeJS `child_process.spawn()`

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn, winget

When running the command `winget upgrade PACKAGE_NAME` within NodeJS `child_process.spawn()`, the progress bar goes to stdout after the download is complete, not while it's downloading. How would I make it so I can detect every time progress has been made in downloading the file rather than after it's done downloading?

**Current:**

```js
[
    'starting...',
    '\b \r\r  ██████▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒  17.0 MB / 79.4 MB\r  ████████████████▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒  43.0 MB / 79.4 MB\r  ████████████████████████▒▒▒▒▒▒  64.0 MB / 79.4 MB\r  ██████████████████████████▒▒▒▒  70.0 MB / 79.4 MB\r  █████████████████████████████▒  77.0 MB / 79.4 MB\r  ██████████████████████████████  79.4 MB / 79.4 MB\r\n',
    'done!',
]
```

**What I want:**

```js
[
    'starting...',
    '\b \r\r  ██████▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒  17.0 MB / 79.4 MB',
    '\r  ████████████████▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒  43.0 MB / 79.4 MB',
    '\r  ████████████████████████▒▒▒▒▒▒  64.0 MB / 79.4 MB',
    '\r  ██████████████████████████▒▒▒▒  70.0 MB / 79.4 MB',
    '\r  █████████████████████████████▒  77.0 MB / 79.4 MB\r',
    '\r  ██████████████████████████████  79.4 MB / 79.4 MB\r\n',
    'done!',
]
```

Comment: Try [`{stdio:'inherit'}`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#:~:text=%27inherit%27%3A%20Pass%20through%20the%20corresponding%20stdio%20stream%20to/from%20the%20parent%20process.%20In%20the%20first%20three%20positions%2C%20this%20is%20equivalent%20to%20process.stdin%2C%20process.stdout%2C%20and%20process.stderr%2C%20respectively.%20In%20any%20other%20position%2C%20equivalent%20to%20%27ignore%27.)?

Comment: @RickyMo i cant read the stdout with that